# git log --quiet is not quiet

Tags: git

`git diff --quiet` returns exit code as documented.

`git log --quiet` behaves exactly as without quiet.

Did I miss something from the docs:

```
--quiet 
    Disable all output of the program. Implies --exit-code.
```

git 1.6.0

This is supposed to be used in a script to compare mybranch with origin/mybranch, to know should I push it or not.

Comment: There is a discussion about this here: http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-02/msg00537.html

Comment: what's exactly the purpose of `--quiet` on `git log` anyway?

Comment: well, I want to use exit code in a script

Comment: coelhudo: Yes, I also was thinking of `git rev-list origin/master..master | wc -l` suggested there as a solution. But it seems to me that git log --quiet would a more straightforward way if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rev-list -1 origin/master..master | wc -l
```

from the link suggested in the comments seems to be the best answer here